# How can I append some string to function name.

Tags: c#, click, string-concatenation

I have a for loop which calls click event every time. I want to append some string to the function name. 
say, button_click then I want it to be Button_click1, Button_click2 etc..

I want to perform some operation on values 1, 2 etc.. 
Please suggest if there is any other way to access this information.

Thread can be the last option I would opt.

Comment: The method name is irrelevant when you're actually running the code (mostly). What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to call multiple methods on the same object, where each method name is the same except the number suffix that you plan to retrieve from for loop index ?

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are more correct for my money, but If you *really* need string based invocation  I think you'll need to use the Reflection classes.

```
String suffix = "_Click1";
Type myType = typeof(MyClass);
myType.InvokeMember("Button"+ suffix, 
            BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, yourButtonObject, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a Button array in and then you can create an event for a click of any button in the array.

Than, You can use a for loop that closes over a variable containing the current index:

```
for(int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
{
    //it's important to have this; closing over the loop variable would be bad
    int index = i;  
    buttons[i].Click += (sender, args) => SomeMethod(buttons[index], index);
}
```

This probably would be going to save a lot lines of code and easier as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just put all buttons in a list like so:

```
List<Button> ButtonList = new List<Button>(){Button1, Button2};
```

And then just call Button_Click for each of those buttons like so:

```
Foreach(Button button in ButtonList)
    button.Button_Click(this, new EventArgs());
```